# How to use a custom request handler in Solarium

Tags: solr, solarium

I have set up a request handler /query in solr. Now, when I use this code, it does not work but if I change "query" to "select" it works fine.

```
// create a client instance
$client = new Solarium\Client($config);


// create a select query instance
$query = $client->createQuery('query'); // change query to select and it works fine
```

Please let me know. I have tried to search a few hours but there is no answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it. I used this

```
// create a select query instance
$query = $client->createSelect();
$query->setQuery('bird');

// manually create a request for the query
$request = $client->createRequest($query);
$request->setHandler('query');
```

So, the result of URI is:

```
Request URI: query?omitHeader=true&wt=json&json.nl=flat&q=bird&start=0&rows=10&fl=%2A%2Cscore
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use $select array

```
$select = array(
   'handler'       => 'yourCustomRequestHandler',
   'start'         => 0,
   'rows'          => 10,
);

// create a select query instance
$query = $this->client->createSelect($select);
```

Another options check [Building a select query](https://solarium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/queries/select-query/building-a-select-query/building-a-select-query/)